# Meteor: Passing value to database after successful Paypal payment

Tags: meteor, paypal

I'd like to update the users database after a successful payment. Basically, converting $ to site credits. I've used https://github.com/tirtohadi/meteor-paypal-demo/, basically using his code implementing paypal to the web app. The only idea I have is when the site gets routed to the return page after payment. Code's here.

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('/payment_return/:invoice_no/:amount/', {
        where: 'server',
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            console.log("result");
            result = paypal_return(this.params.invoice_no,this.params.amount,this.params.query.token,this.params.query.PayerID);
            console.log(result);
            if (result)
            {
                this.response.end("Payment captured successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                this.response.end("Error in processing payment");
            }


        }
    });
});
```

I guess my question is, how do I securely update the db after a successful payment. Because I know client side update is dangerous (from what I've read anyway)

Comment: I have never done PayPal payments.  I assume there is some sort of callback URL you hand PayPal and it forwards back when it's done. Can you control the callback URL?  If so, could you use a dynamic URL path URL that contains a confirmation code?  Then you could use the confirmation code to match up the payment with the user that made it, apply the credit, and continue.

Comment: this code is in the js. http://pastebin.com/pDdgcAnd i think we can control the variables. i could be wrong. i watched how the op built this and he avoided using curl. please correct me if im wrong... if you have time to quickly glance at the code to give some insight pls

Comment: Yeah, it looks like he is using the technique I described, only he is calling it the `transaction.invoice_no` and I called it the "confirmation code".  So, when he sets up the payment he tells PayPal "when it's done, confirm on the URL "http://my.domain/payment_return/12345678/12.57", where 12345678 is the number you will us to look up the user's cart and 12.57 is the total price (not sure why you'd want to send that, seems like a security issue to me).  The code that executes behind that URL will use the invoice_no to look up the invoice and mark it "paid".

Comment: so i shouldnt return the amount for the return url? is there a more secure way to update db.users (credits)? I tried adding something like Session.set(amount) but it says session not defined even tho i added the package. but that method doesnt seem too safe considerin its client side

Comment: I wouldn't pass anything on the URL except the transaction id.  And that ID should be a generated number, not something visible on the page, and should not be a reversible hash.  You should store all the relevant bits (user, items in cart, price, invoice number, etc) in your DB and look them up via the unique generated number you are using for the callback.  You should also remove the code once you have confirmed their payment via the callback url. Otherwise, what prevents people from passing in their own price or marking their invoice as paid?

Comment: How do I do this then? I've added this in route.js http://pastebin.com/61mVCqGh, but its returning with  Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.. For now I want to try to get the functions workin before securing the app

Comment: basically i wanna update the db.users collection upon return

Comment: The error you see is saying that `Meteor.userId` is not available inside a method.  You have to use `this.userId`.  You can update a collection from a method call, and in fact most people argue it's the more secure way to do it instead of allowing client-side updates directly.

Comment: so in my code, instead of Meteor.user(), i use this.userId, it should increase yes? I've done this, no errors returned, however profile.tokens not updated..

Comment: okay, just checked dev console, it is undefined, however Meteor.userId returns the id..

Comment: You cannot update using `this.userId` directly.  You use that to look up the user in the `Meteor.users` collection when you do your update.  The user object is just a document in a collection.  The only thing special about it is that Meteor provides the collection through `Meteor.users` and it auto-populates `Meteor.user()`, `Meteor.userId()`, and `this.userId` accordingly with the current user's info.

Comment: ahhh so it's not really used as a reference but more just displaying the data in the collection? so how does one update an attribute in a collection from the template/client side?

Comment: In Meteor, by default, clients can write to their local Mini-Mongo, and the underlying Meteor code will sync that to the server.  However, this is frowned upon as it poses a security risk, so most people turn off the ability for clients to write through to the server.  Instead, the preferred method is to use a `Meteor.method` and call that from the client.  There, you have the option to update only on the server and let DDP sync to the client, or to us "optimistic UI" and update in both the client and server at the same time.